# Abusive content

Tags: discussion

Maybe some of you have notice that we've had some abusive content lately, which was caused a particular user. I have destroyed all of the corresponding accounts, including some content that might not have seemed abusive in the first place. However, I have reason to suspect that this user puts non abusive content to somehow game some automatic detection mechanisms, and therefore is probably irrelevant.

Please do not hesitate to flag for moderator attention if you see something suspicious!

Answer (score 3):

As a side note: when users flag content as abusive (which is a different checkbox than “needs moderator attention”), it can be destroyed without moderator action (enough “abusive” flags will simply delete the post). So, if the content is clearly abusive, we can flag as such (and avoid some work for the mods)!